# S3 URL example for GET Bucket (List Objects) request

Tags: url, amazon-s3

Using [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) I managed to generate URLs to get objects from my bucket. I am generating a canonical request in the follwing way:

```
            String canonicalRequest = 'GET' + '\n'
                + key + '\n'
                + 'X-Amz-Algorithm=' + algorithm
                + '&X-Amz-Credential=' + credential
                + '&X-Amz-Date=' + creationDateTime
                + '&X-Amz-Expires=' + expires
                + '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\n'
                + 'host:' + bucketName + '.s3.amazonaws.com\n\n'
                + 'host\n'
                + 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD';
```

During execution it looks like:

```
GET
/123/white.jpg
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=...%2F...%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170727T162258Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:b0gdan1.s3.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
```

It works fine. There is an example of output URL:

```
https://b0gdan1.s3.amazonaws.com/123/white.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=...%2F20170727%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170727T162258Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=...
```

When I use the empty string as a key for this example, it returns me a list of all objects in my bucket. However, I have to somehow filter objects by prefix. In other words, I have to create a GET request to list prefix-filtered objects in my bucket. [This documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) looks like a good one. However, it contains only canonical requests. I have no clue how my URL should look like. 
My canonical request for this case is:

```
            String canonicalRequest = 'GET \n'
                + '/?list-type=2&prefix='+ prefix + '\n'
                + 'X-Amz-Credential=' + credential
                + '&X-Amz-Date=' + creationDateTime
                + '&X-Amz-Expires=' + expires + '\n'
                + '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host\n'
                + 'host:' + bucketName + '.s3.amazonaws.com\n\n'
                + 'host\n'
                + 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD';
```

During execution it looks like:

```
GET
/?list-type=2&prefix=123
X-Amz-Credential=...%2F20170727%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170727T164952Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:b0gdan1.s3.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
```

Than I use this URL:

```
https://b0gdan1.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=123&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=...%2F20170727%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170727T164412Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=...
```

But it returns me SignatureDoesNotMatch error. I tried a lot of variations of canonical requests and URLs, even much more weird than presented ones, but I had tough luck. It would be great if someone provides me an example URL that lists objects of the bucket. Please, let me know if I need to provide any additional details to explain my issue.

I know that I can simply achieve it using something like AWS SDK for Java, but I do not have an opportunity to do it.

Comment: Side-question: Any particular reason why you are constructing your own URLs rather than using an [official AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) or the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)? It would be a lot simpler.

Comment: I work on solution that is a Salesforce managed package. Thus I have to do everything from scratch. I wish I could use any AWS SDK as a solution. Btw, I use AWS SDK for Java for exploratory purposes, but I have not found have to get the URL of ListObjectsRequest.

Comment: [Amazon Web Services SDK for Salesforce Apex](https://github.com/bigassforce/aws-sdk)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot just install this package, but I believe I can investigate it to fix my request. Thank you very much, sir!